# Can't connect to the server - error "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**Not possible to connect to PostgreSQL 11.**

Event though the server is running. I even installed pgAdmin 4, accessed the server, it is working perfectly. But when I do it from the Rails server it shows:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>   Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

I tried every possible thing here in Stackoverflow. Two days straight, and nothing. The same thing with PostgreSQL 10. Log files checked, the file `.s.PGSQL.5432` does not appear in the `/var/run/postgresql` folder.

I am using bash Ubuntu 18.04.2 subsystem on Windows. I checked for permissions already.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the setting of `unix_socket_directories` on your PostgreSQL server. It probably does not contain `/var/run/postgresql`.

Here is what to do:

- Find a directory in `unix_socket_directories`.
- Make sure that the client has access to the directory and the socket file in it.
- Use the name of the directory as `host` parameter for your database connection.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was that Rails default port was 5432 while postgresql was going to 5433, I downgraded to version 10 though. Not sure if this was the deal. Also this issue seems to be related with installing PostgreSql as a linux subsystem on Windows, and I will have to use either Docker, or Ubuntu